# Grab html frame by name using javascript

Tags: javascript, frame, same-origin-policy

I want to find a frame by name. I can detect the corresponding frameset and I know that my frame has the name 'body'. How can I handle this? Is it possible to use jQuery for this? Furthermore the frames are not on the same domain, so later I have to think about Same origin policy as well (I want to set the value for the src-element), so maybe you can tell me a solution which handles both issues. Thanks in advance.

My Html:

```
<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="50,*">
<frame noresize="noresize" name="navigation" src="xxx"></frame>
<frame name="body" src="yyy"></frame>
</frameset>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var framesets = self.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("FRAMESET");
var firstFrameset = framesets[0];
var bodyFrameList = firstFrameset.document.getElementsByName("body"); // Baaamm!
var matches = bodyFrameList.length;
var bodyFrame = bodyFrameList[0];
```

My JQuery-trial on this, didn't work either:

```
var firstFrameset = framesets[0];
var $firstFrameset = jQuery(firstFrameset);
var bodyFrameList = $firstFrameset('frame[name=body]');
```

Comment: Why are you using frames at all?

Comment: You can refer to the body-frame like this: `top.frames['body']` or simply `top.body`. However, you can't get any reference to `top` when having cross-domained pages.